# How to compare two byte arrays in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to compare two byte arrays in Python.

This is my code

```
print("new_digest: ", new_digest)
print("digest: ", digest)
if digest == new_digest:
    return True
else:
    return False
```

and this is the output:

```
new_digest:  b"<\xc3\xb8\xa9'3\x81\xa2\xfb\xf7\xbfCm\xa8\xd6O\xd0\x03\xdd\xfadW\xfd,\xed\x03\\m\x87\xf8*"

digest:  b"<\xc3\xb8\xa9'3\x81\xa2\xfb\xf7\xbfCm\xa8\xd6O\xd0\x03\xdd\xfadW\xfd,\xed\x03\\m\x87\xf8*"
```

It is clear that they are equal but the function is returning false. Why is this?

The byte streams are generated using

```
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes
digest = hashes.Hash(hashes.SHA256())
digest.update(message)
digest = digest.finalize()
```

Comment: How is `new_digest` generated in the code at the bottom?

Comment: To answer the title question, using `==` is the correct way.

Comment: Print `repr(new_digest)` and `repr(digest)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Their Types could be different.Also I recommend you to use

```
return digest == new_digest
```

instead

```
if digest == new_digest:
    return True
else:
   return False
```

compare

> type(digest) and type(new_digest)

if it won't work, convert to string and strip them.

> `.strip()`

Comment: yes thanks you were right, one was a string and the other was bytes